# how to remove tomcat 9.0.36 from maven dependency. how to give access to pivotal embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using STS, with embedded Pivotal 3.2. the problem is during runtime its throwing exception. there is two 2 tomcat, one in my project maven dependency and second in pivotal, so i want to remove tomcat 9.0.36 from my maven. how to do that?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cloudpoint</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootSecuritylogin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springbootSecuritylogin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Console output**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-07-20 10:49:00.155  INFO 5984 --- [           main] c.c.SpringbootSecurityloginApplication   : Starting SpringbootSecurityloginApplication on DESKTOP-JK4E6SS with PID 5984 (F:\download\springbootSecuritylogin\springbootSecuritylogin\target\classes started by CP_Associate in F:\download\springbootSecuritylogin\springbootSecuritylogin)
2020-07-20 10:49:00.161  INFO 5984 --- [           main] c.c.SpringbootSecurityloginApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-20 10:49:01.063  INFO 5984 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-07-20 10:49:01.133  INFO 5984 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 61ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-07-20 10:49:01.494  INFO 5984 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@36dce7ed' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-07-20 10:49:01.500  INFO 5984 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-07-20 10:49:01.691  WARN 5984 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V
2020-07-20 10:49:01.714  INFO 5984 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-20 10:49:01.724 ERROR 5984 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
```

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:175)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V
```

The method's class, org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/E:/SetUps/STS/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.8.RELEASE/tomcat-8.5.23.A.RELEASE/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/CP_Associate/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.36/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry: file:/E:/SetUps/STS/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.8.RELEASE/tomcat-8.5.23.A.RELEASE/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry

Comment: Are you deploying your app to Tomcat?

Comment: For some reason you added pivotal tomcat to your dependencies, remove it from the list of manually added dependencies, don't mess around with excludes in maven as that will make it unusable.